# VBScript For Next Loop By Month And Increment

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to perform a task and I am quite new to `vbscript` but I understand most of the basics and a little advanced stuff. I am trying to perform a `for-loop` so when the month changes it will still do the new month and also increment the ID by 1, I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Can't understand the problem at all. Please provide an example in the OP and also any code that you have tried

Answer (score -1):

I actually answered the question my self and im hoping this will work.

```
Dim i
i = month(now())
Dim deMonth 
deMonth = month(now())
for I = deMonth to I

                sql insert here
Next
```